# Odoo Studio Server Error Computed Fields, Error

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I keep getting this error , what am I missing?
I've tried multiple approaches and I always get this error I am sure im missing something simple.
Example image of Odoo setup in image link

[image: Odoo Compute Settings]

```
from odoo import api
x_studio_field_CKrxZ = fields.Float(compute='compute_product_dimension', store=True)
@api.depends('list_price','standard_price')
def compute_product_dimension(self):
  for record in self:
      record['compute_product_dimension'] = record.list_price + record.standard_price
```

Error in Odoo

```
ValueError: forbidden opcode(s) in "from odoo import api\r\nx_studio_field_CKrxZ = fields.Float(compute='compute_product_dimension', store=True)\r\n@api.depends('list_price','standard_price')\r\ndef compute_product_dimension(self):\r\n  for record in self:\r\n      record['compute_product_dimension'] = record.list_price + record.standard_price \r\n": IMPORT_NAME, IMPORT_FROM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computed field function is executed in Odoo's sandboxed implementation of `eval` called [`safe_eval`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/45dec698ee2b113c19277dbc39abcb4f0897da16/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py#L306). It forbids certain Python interpreter opcodes to prevent arbitrary code execution.  The error you are getting is because the [`IMPORT_NAME`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-IMPORT_NAME) and [`IMPORT_FROM`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-IMPORT_FROM) opcodes [are not allowed](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/45dec698ee2b113c19277dbc39abcb4f0897da16/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py#L95) (caused by the `from odoo import api` statement).

You should not need the import statement, field declaration, `@api.depends` decorator or the compute function signature definition, your compute method should look something like this:

```py
for record in self:
    record['x_studio_field_CKrxZ'] = record.list_price + record.standard_price
```

Instead of the `@api.depends('list_price','standard_price')`, the field's dependencies should be declared in the *Dependencies* field under *Advanced Properties*, which you already did as seen in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This does not apply to your specific situation, but rather the error in general.

Another cause for this error is when accessing the record attribute for storing.

```
for record in self:
    record.somefield = record.someotherfield
```

turns out the first reference isn't allowed: the op code is: `STORE_ATTR`

the second reference is fine.

Almost drove me crazy, thinking the two would be treated equally.